# Firefox on Windows not loading @FontFace resource

Tags: css, windows, firefox, browser, fonts

So I have a bit of a problem. On this page http://www.tylermorriswoodworking.com/pages/recipe-box-engraving-wizard?b=maple&l=cherry&s=3x5&c=42042892 I have a few @FontFace tags to load the custom fonts. On all the browsers it works just fine, except for Firefox for windows. Firefox for mac loads the fonts perfectly. What I am doing wrong? It would be great if someone could also confirm this problem on other Windows machines because I only have one windows so it might be computer specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also asked here:
[Firefox 3.5 on a Mac and @font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101544/firefox-3-5-on-a-mac-and-font-face)

To ensure that your font will always display, you need to serve quite a few variations. The font generator on Font Squirrel is a good place to start- it includes the EOT, TTF or OTF and a WOFF & SVG version as well:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Oh thanks. I knew the answer had something to do with that. Also thanks for the link to the other post!